# What does type '()' refer to in Swift

Tags: swift

```
for i in stride(from: -13, to: 13, by: 2) {
    print(13-(pow(pow(Double(i), Double(2)), Double(0.5)))) / 2
}
```

I have this code in Swift which returns "Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type '()' and 'Int'"

Comment: `print(...) / 2`?  Does that seem strange to you?

Comment: Essentially, you're dividing the print statement by 2. But a pair of braces around the final result i.e. print((number/2))

Comment: To directly answer your question, `()` means `Void`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to divide the result of the `print` function (`()`) by 2. You probably meant to divide the number you give to the print expression, instead.

This is the importance of clean code :)

```
for i in stride(from: -13, to: 13, by: 2) {
    print(13 - ( pow(pow(Double(i), 2), 0.5) / 2 ))
}
```

Note:

1. `Double` conforms to the `ExpressibleByDoubleLiteral` protocol (obviously, that's why you can do `let d: Double = 0.5`), but that protocol itself inherits from `ExpressbileByIntegerLiteral`. That means that anything that you can initialize from a double literal (e.g. `1.0`), you can initialize from an integer literal (e.g. `2`). So don't write thing like `Double(2)`. Keep it simple and just write `2`.
2. `()` has two meanings:

   1. It is the type of the empty tuple. It is typealiased to `Void`.

      - Functions that don't return anything else explicitly, return a value of this type. `print` is an example of a function that doesn't return anything, thus it returns nothing, which is `()`.

        ```
        // These are all equivalent:
        func f() {...
        func f() -> () {...
        func f() -> Void {...
        ```
   2. It is the only possible value of the empty tuple.

      - Functions that don't return anything else explicitly, return this value.

        ```
        func f() {
            return () // equivalent to `return` on it own
        }
        ```